# Modifying Pioneer Radio

Tags: audio, electronics

I would like to add iPhone integration to an old Honda Accord. Pioneer makes a nice line of radios that integrate well with iPhones. The feature that stands out to me the most is the ability to launch Siri right from the radio itself. You do so by long pressing the call button located towards the left of most of their radios. I am trying to make Siri use in the car the least distracting possible, so I would like the ability to trigger that functionality form the steering wheel. I have some basic soldering skills and I am hoping the call button is just a tactile switch. I can solder some wires to the connectors on the circuit board, and add an external switch to the steering wheel for calls and Siri. That is the plan anyway.

Does anyone have any experience gutting one of these Pioneer radios, and are the switches something I can solder too?

Comment: Siri has the ability to take voice commands to initiate a call. Wouldn't that be easier to use than modifying your car stereo? [The complete list of Siri commands](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/the-complete-list-of-siri-commands/)

Comment: Yeah, it’s just Pioneer used the same button for calls and Siri

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I was referring to the ability to talk to your phone ("Hey Siri") with commands so you don't have to touch any buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Most vehicles with steering wheel controls require a separate control adapter which allows you to integrate the steering wheel controls with the aftermarket radio, such as this [PAC SWI-RC from Crutchfield](https://www.crutchfield.com/p_541SWIRC/PAC-SWI-RC-Steering-Wheel-Control-Adapter.html?tp=3405) (Note: I'm not affiliated with Crutchfield, this is just an example. This is the adapter I used in my wife's car when I put in a Pioneer head unit.) With it, you can set the buttons to do whatever you want to do, without the need to solder or tearing a new head unit apart to get it to do what you need it to do. Sort of anticlimactic, I get it, but it will save you a lot of trouble and hassle rather than the alternative.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll look into this. This is probably a much better solution cause I won’t void my warrantee